# CSS3 -transition-

Tags: html, css, webkit, css-transitions

I have a navigation bar which i am using css to highlight on hover and when the li has class active. I would like to has a transition to fade the background in. This is what I have so far:

CSS:

```
#nav {height:32px; border-top: 1px solid #fff; border-right: 1px solid #FFFFFF; background: #141941 url('../img/topTierBG.gif') repeat-x; }
#nav ul {padding: 0px; list-style: none; height:32px; width:100%;  }
#nav li { position:relative; float: left; margin:0; border-left:1px solid #fff; line-height:30px; background: #141941 url('../img/topTierBG.gif') repeat-x; padding-top:0px;}
#nav a, #nav a:link, #nav a:visited, #nav a:hover, #nav a:active {width:156px; display:block; text-align:center; font-size:12px; text-decoration:none; color:#fff; margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px; -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear; -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear; -o-transition: background 0.5s linear; transition: background 0.5s linear; }
#nav .active {text-align:center; text-decoration:none; padding:0; color:#fff; height:32px; background: #1D2248 url('../img/activeTab.gif') repeat-x; }
#nav a:hover, #nav a:active{background: #1D2248 url('../img/activeTab.gif') repeat-x; -webkit-transition: background 0.5s linear; -moz-transition: background 0.5s linear; -o-transition: background 0.5s linear; transition: background 0.5s linear; }
```

html:

```
<div id="nav"><ul id="xmp-nav">
<li class="active"><a href="/" style="width:196px;">HOME</a></li>
<li><a href="login.php" style="width:195px;">STAFF LOGIN</a></li>
<li><a href="resources.php" style="width:195px;">RESOURCES</a></li>
<li><a href="information.php" style="width:195px;">PARENT INFORMATION</a></li>
<li><a href="links.php" class="last" style="width:195px;">LINKS</a></li>
</ul></div>
```

Problem is that when i hover over a non-active tab the transition doesn't happen but when i hover over the already active tab is transitions from the non-active style to the active style.

I look forward to hearing your ideas, if it is not possible with the way i have laid it out no problem.

[Here is a link!](http://sen.dpwebdev.co.uk)

Comment: Transforms are not transitions. Please don't get them mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Transitions works this way:

1. You have element with state A (for example **li**).
2. You change elements state to B (for example by adding new class to **li** or adding **:hover** to it) which changing it's properties (for example **background: red**).
3. In the new class/state you are adding transition, and set which property to animate (for example **background**).

And now you can see smooth animation.

In your example you have two transitions:

1. **"transition: background 0.5s linear;"** on **#nav a** — it didn't work because there is no background change in **#nav a** on hover.
2. **transition: background 0.5s linear;** on **#nav a:hover, #nav a:active** — it means change background of **"#nav a"** from **"none"**, to **"background: #1D2248 url('../img/activeTab.gif') repeat-x;"** with linear animation in 0.5s.

I made simplified jsfiddle from you code that shows how to change animations on hover:

http://jsfiddle.net/hzTwz/

Answer (score 0):

Here you have a simplified fiddle that maybe helps you. You only need to add transition and -webkit-transition to your element, and then when you change the background color on hover, it acts with the transition that you can custom yourself.

Hope it helps.

Here's the code:

```
li{
float: left;
padding: 10px 15px 10px 15px;
background: red;
cursor: pointer;
transition: background 1s;
-webkit-transition: background 1s;}

li:hover{
background: blue;}
```

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ManelMusti/XNm3b/)